# Multi Class Classification using XGBClassifier

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, xgboost, softmax, multiclass-classification

I am using XGBClassifier for multiclass classification(5 classes - [1,2,3,4,5]). I have set objective parameter as 'multi:softmax' but still when I predict using my model I am getting continuous values instead of integers.

I tried with specifying num_class parameter too, but still it predicts continuous values.

`model  = XGBClassifier(learning_rate = 0.1,n_estimators = 200, objective='multi:softmax')`

`model.fit(x1, y1, eval_set=[(x1,y1),(x2, y2)], eval_metric='mlogloss')`

Expected output = [1,2,3,3,2,3,4,4,5,5,1.... etc] #integers values

Actual Output = [2.334, 1.455, 2.122, 1.76 .... etc] #continuous values

Comment: My bad guys, I manipulated the target variable and made it continuous. Hence was getting continuous values

Comment: But how can an `XGBClassifier` output continuous values? Were you using `XGBRegressor`?

Comment: @VivekKumar Actually I should describe them as float and not continuous, and no I wasn't using XGBRegressor.